# Nginx and multiple React Web Apps

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I want to do some A/B testing in a React Web App and decided to duplicate it.

So I'm tring to set one app in the root location (example.com) and the other into a sub-folder (example.com/bversion).

For this, I'm using nginx for serve both versions.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /var/www/html/a_version;

    location / {    
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location /bversion {
        root /var/www/html/b_version;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
}
```

The problem is that Ngnix never resolve /bversion. Always return the root A version of my app.
If I remove try_files in both locations, I lose the possibility to access directly to some specific pages of the application (e.g. example.com/hello or example.com/bversion/hello)